# UIWebBrowserView does not span entire UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, uiwebview

So I have been trying to get this simple behavior working on my iPhone app now for a while. I have a nav bar at the top and a tab bar at the bottom. I am loading all of my content in a webview, which I want to fit between the two. I have posted about this issue twice already,

both here: [IOS View still does not load in the correct position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083413/ios-view-still-does-not-load-in-the-correct-position)

and here: [Programmatically setting content to fill screen between tab bar and nav controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773155/programmatically-setting-content-to-fill-screen-between-tab-bar-and-nav-controll)

Currently, my webview looks and performs fine on iPhone 4 and 4s, the issue arises on the 5s. When the screen finishes loading, it looks like the image here: http://grosh.co/screen.jpg . This occurs on both the simulator as well as devices.

Upon further inspection, I discovered that the UIWebView is in fact spanning correctly (the grey areas you see are the webview). The smaller content is actually a **UIWebBrowserView**, which I am having a hard time finding any information on.

I have the code I am using below, as well as a log output to insure all the numbers are correct. My questions are,

1) Is there a better way to set the webview to span the screen area between the top and bottom bars for all devices?

2) If not, is there a way to set the UIWebBrowser to span the entire webview?

I tried iterating over the subviews of the webview as described here: http://normansoven.com/ios-webview/#.VHyOUr6Jnww but the webBrowserView was never seen.

Teh Codez:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    


CGFloat viewheight = self.view.bounds.size.height;
NSLog(@"Height1:%f",viewheight);

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat viewheight2 = screenRect.size.height;
NSLog(@"Height2:%f",viewheight2);

CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;
NSLog(@"Height3:%f",height);


CGFloat navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
NSLog(@"NAVHeight:%f",navBarHeight);

CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
NSLog(@"TABHeight:%f",tabBarHeight);

CGFloat statusbarheight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
NSLog(@"StatbarHeight:%f",statusbarheight);

CGFloat spaceToRemove = navBarHeight + tabBarHeight + statusbarheight;
    NSLog(@"NAVHeight+TABHeight:%f",spaceToRemove);
CGFloat newHeight = viewheight - spaceToRemove;
        NSLog(@"NewHeight:%f",newHeight);

CGRect frame =  CGRectMake(0 , navBarHeight + statusbarheight, self.view.frame.size.width, newHeight);

self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];


//self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];


[self.view addSubview:self.webView];

self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/finnaRoot/index.php"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];
self.webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;


self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];

self.webView.delegate = self;
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;

}
```

Log output, from an iPhone 5s

```
2014-11-26 17:19:21.184 Finna[14617:1765689] Height1:568.000000
2014-11-26 17:19:21.185 Finna[14617:1765689] Height2:568.000000
2014-11-26 17:19:21.185 Finna[14617:1765689] Height3:568.000000
2014-11-26 17:19:21.185 Finna[14617:1765689] NAVHeight:44.000000
2014-11-26 17:19:21.185 Finna[14617:1765689] TABHeight:49.000000
2014-11-26 17:19:21.185 Finna[14617:1765689] StatbarHeight:20.000000
2014-11-26 17:19:21.185 Finna[14617:1765689] NAVHeight+TABHeight:113.000000
2014-11-26 17:19:21.186 Finna[14617:1765689] NewHeight:455.000000
```

Comment: So the latest iOS update fixed this issue, which leads me to believe it was a bug. I will add the workaround code I used below when I get a chance. It worked and the app was accepted to the store.

Answer (score 8):

I've encountered with the same problem.
And found simple fix.
The culprit is `UIViewController`'s property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`. `UIViewController` reference says:

> Default value is `YES`, which allows the view controller to adjust its
>   scroll view insets in response to the screen areas consumed by the
>   status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar.

It means that `UIViewController` adds that top gap to `UIWebView`'s scroll view even if you properly set up webview frame or add autolayout constraints. To overcome this behaviour just

> Set to `NO` if you
>   want to manage scroll view inset adjustments yourself, such as when
>   there is more than one scroll view in the view hierarchy.

*"manage scroll view inset adjustments your self"* in our context means that we won't add any insets ;)

same issue with any scroll view, i.e. [Blank space at top of UITextView in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931934/blank-space-at-top-of-uitextview-in-ios-7/18932245#18932245)
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets

Answer (score 4):

This issue has also resurfaced with iPhone X.

With iOS 11, UIScrollView now has the property contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.

webview.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;

can correct this issue.

Comment: Worked out great for me, but needed an additional wrapping with @available: 


    <!-- language: objective-c -->
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        self.webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
    }